# Should the [dota] tag be used ONLY for the Warcraft 3 map?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see plenty of questions on Arqade that are about DoTA 2, the Valve game, rather than the actual Warcraft map. Most of the time, these questions also tend to have both `[dota]` and `[dota-2]` tags.

The tag wiki for `[dota]` even talks about the map. So, **does this mean the `[dota]` tag should not be used for questions relating to the Valve game?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. They're different games and the tag should be about the game that it is talking about not it's prequel/sequel. You wouldn't tag a Starcraft 2 question with the [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) or a CS:GO question with [counter-strike-source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-source).

If a question is about dota 2 then it should be [dota-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota-2). Similarly if the game is about the first dota (the Warcraft 3 map) then it should be [dota](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota).

You're right, the tag's Wiki answers your question: [dota](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota) "The original WarCraft 3 map..."

A question should not have both tags unless the question is regarding something from both, maybe the lore or something since I think it would be the same for either game.

Comment: Generally, if there's a need for questions about every game in a series, we'll have a series tag, like [tag:dota-series].

Comment: @StrixVaria yeh starcraft has a series one, dota doesn't though

Comment: @Aequitas - Tags are created as they are needed. Searching for [\[*-series\]](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-series) gives a list of all the series tags currently being used.

Comment: So once Valve finally counts to three, which tag should a sub-300 use?

Comment: @tepples I'm not sure what you're asking, are you saying what tag to use when dota 3 is released? A new [tag:dota-3] will be created and that one will be used. What do you mean by "sub-300"? If you're referring to the ability to create tags, don't worry about it someone else will create it for you

Comment: "Sub-300" means it takes 300 rep to create [tag:dota-3] and a lot of people won't have that much.